# Database logon error using Crystal Reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have the following bit of simple code, which based on tutorials should work:

```
Try
   Dim report As CustomerStatus = New CustomerStatus
   report.Load("Reports/CustomerStatus.rpt")

   report.SetParameterValue("id_customer", 130)
   report.SetDatabaseLogon("root", "", "localhost", "aerospace")

   report.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "c:\customer_status.pdf")

Catch ex As Exception
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Regardless of whether I directly connect (SetDatabaseLogon) or use the details specified at report compilation, I get this error:

```
"Database Logon Failed."
```

I have also tried connecting to a local and production server and neither works.

I am using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2012 Professional.

Comment: You should show your error details.

Comment: How do I get at those? Sorry but it's been over a decade since I seriously used VB.NET so consider me a total newb :)

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking?

Comment: Well any errors I can see I have included in the first question...no exception is thrown so I am not sure what other error details you are asking for??? How do I see what they are...I only get a dialogbox saying "Database Logon Failed."

Comment: I am updating your question to reflect this.

Comment: Are you specifying your root password in your code? Did you just remove it for the code insert?

Comment: I removed it for code insert that is correct. Actually it's a localhost so it's a development copy - but I have tried both and no avail. DB credentials are correct as I can use the wizard, connect, see my tables (datasets) and begin building reports but when I try to load PDF programmatically...poof it all fails

Comment: Maybe someone will come along and help you out.

Comment: What kind of database are you connecting to? Access / SQL Server etc

Comment: MySQL - I've updated all the ODBC drivers and such - VS/CR can connect to the server(s) no problems as I can build my reports in VS but when I go to run and export is when everything seems to fall apart. Seems the error comes from ExportToDisk() oddly enough

Answer (score 0):

Crystal engine sometimes has issues when you use "localhost", try with the actual server name instead

Comment: It's definetely the connection not working...I tried a preview with a CrystalReportViewer and it prompted me for connection details...how would the report builder see the tables and fields if the connection didn't work???

Comment: are you changing the server and database name?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where only certain reports would fail with this error but only on the first run - e.g after the app pool was just started. Subsequent attempt to run the report had no error. As soon as the app pool w3wp.exe process was killed and restarted the error would occur. In my particular case I was running CR2008 (v 12) and the database was SQL Server 2008 R2 located on the same server with the asp.net application running the reports. The ap pool was enabled for 32 bit applications.
The solution was to enable the TCPIP connections in the SQL Server Configuration manager. By default only named pipes was enabled.
After enabling TCPIP and restarting SQL Server the error went away.